# How to increase size of switch control Xamarin forms?

Tags: android, xamarin, multiplatform

I recently just started working with Xamarin Forms and have the task of switching a working iOS project to Droid. It's a multiplatform project so I'm creating the switch in the shared project, but trying to manage its style in .Droid styles.xml or a custom renderer. I'm needing the control to be a bit larger for the tablets.

Using styles.xml, I was able to change the width of the switch control using this line:

```
<item name="switchMinWidth">120dp</item>
```

But to my knowledge there's no way to change the height of the control in this manner. I've tried using a custom renderer and used the SetHeight, SetMinHeight, and SetMinimumHeight methods of the Control (Android.Switch.Widget) but nothing is working.

Here's what the switches look like currently:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwenv.jpg

I've also tried doing a HeightRequest in the xaml itself but it doesn't change the actual height of the control. Is there anything I can do to make these switches a little taller?

Comment: Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How to increase size of switch control Xamarin forms?

`Switch` height is controlled by `<switch android:track="@drawable/shape_mythumb".../>`,  and the track's height determines the `Switch`'s overall height. So yo could add this property in your custom `SwitchRenderer` :

```
public class MySwitchRenderer : SwitchRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Switch> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.SetTrackResource(Resource.Drawable.track);
        }
    }
}
```

You need custom a [Track](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Switch.html#attr_android:track) layout, you could draw a shape whatever you want.

**Example :**

#### track.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_on"
      android:state_checked="true"/>

  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/switch_track_off"
      android:state_checked="false"/>

</selector>
```

#### switch_track_on.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

  <corners
       android:radius="15dp" />
  <size
       android:width="75dp"
       android:height="25dp" />
  <solid
      android:color="#6decacec" />

</shape>
```

#### switch_track_off.xml

```
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

  <corners
      android:radius="15dp" />
  <size
      android:width="75dp"
      android:height="25dp" />
  <solid
      android:color="#6db3b1b3" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Thank you so very much. All I had to do was add the SetThumbResource in the Custom Renderer and the thumb xml files to go along with the track ones. It's perfect!